# call api controller method in asp.net mvc from angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Hello i have a server side controller method:

public class CustomerController : ApiController
{

public void Delete(IList customers)
        {

```
        // handle delete action here....
    }
```

}

I am using Angularjs , my question is how can i call my delete method from angularjs at client side.

Thanks

Comment: read about $http in docs.angularjs.org

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX request with [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http):

```
var customers = [
   { id: 1, name: 'John' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Smith' }
];

$http({ 
    method: 'DELETE', 
    url: '/customer',
    data: customers
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('success');
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error');
});
```

Comment: method:'DELETE' this is where i have to put the method name? in my case my method'name is Delete so it should put method:'Delete' ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use $http in angularjs rather than normal http.

```
function Delete(customer) {
        var promise = $http.post(
            '/customer',
            { customer: customer}
        ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
```